# How to add two arrays to produce a third one?

Tags: c, arrays

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int integer1[10], integer2[10], integertotal[10];
    int i, j, index;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        integer1[i] = 2 * (i + 4);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("    %d", integer1[i]);

    printf("\n");

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        integer2[j] = 3 * (j + 3);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("    %d", integer2[j]);

    printf("\n");

    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        integertotal[index] = integer1[i] * 12 + integer2[j] * 10;
    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        printf("   %d", integertotal[index]);

    printf("\n\n");

    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        printf("%d %d+%d=%d\n", index, integer1[i], integer2[j], integertotal[index]);
}
```

I expect the output should be:

```
(Integer1)     8    10    12    14    16    18   20   22    24    26
(Integer2)     9    12    15    18    21    24   27   30    33    36 
(Integertotal) 374  484  594    704   814  924  1034  1144  1254  1364
```

But the actual result is:

```
(Integer1)     8    10    12    14    16    18   20   22    24    26
(Integer2)     9    12    15    18    21    24   27   30    33    36 
(Integertotal) 80   92   104    116   128   140   152  164  176   188
```

Comment: In the loop that assigns values to `integertotal[index]`, you are using `i` and `j` for `integer1[i]` and `integer2[j]`. But `i` and `j` are from previous loops. They have not been given values relevant to the new loop. It is not clear what you want to compute, because the expected totals, 374, 484, 594,… do not explain the rule and do not match the code. If you are just trying to add corresponding elements from the two arrays, use the same index for each array subscript.

Comment: Do not declare loop counters like `i` and `j` separately, as in `int i, j, index`. Instead, write them into your loops, as with `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. This keeps it local to the loop; it will vanish after the loop, which will prevent you from reusing it accidentally. (Sometimes a value is wanted or needed after a loop and this form of local declaration cannot be used. But you should use it as a default.)

Comment: Instead of `integertotal[index]=integer1[i]*12+integer2[j]*10`  try to use: integertotal[index]=((integer1[i]*12)+(integer2[j]*10) + (index +1))*2

Comment: Also it is common practice to add a space before and after an operator in C and C++ to increase readability.

Comment: @BishalJaiswal: That will not help. The subscripts are wrong.

Comment: *I expect the output should be [...]* – 8 * 12 + 9 * 10 = 186, not 374.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: How can I let i and j keep the values for the new loop?

Comment: @Swordfish: Sorry, the answer was my mistake.

Comment: @CodingFarmer: If you are just adding element 0 of one array to element 0 of another array and putting the sum in element 0 of the output array, and then repeating with element 1 and so on, then you do not need `i` and `j`. You use one index for for all the arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  @Eric Postpischil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "expected output" you put before is wrong (I think it should be: `186   240   294   348   402   456   510   564   618   672`), and you have unnecessary loops and extra index variables. Check again. This is my approach of what i think you want to do:

```
int main() {

    int integer1[10], integer2[10], integertotal[10];
    int i;    
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        integer1[i] = 2 * (i + 4);
        printf("    %d", integer1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        integer2[i] = 3 * (i + 3);
        printf("    %d", integer2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        integertotal[i] = integer1[i] * 12 + integer2[i] * 10;
        printf("   %d", integertotal[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d %d+%d=%d\n", i, integer1[i], integer2[i], integertotal[i]);  //I don't understand the output you want. 8+9=186? Why?
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: integertotal[i] = integer1[i] * 12 + integer2[i] * 10;   answer should be 8*12+9*10=186

Comment: @CodingFarmer and it is. What's the problem?

Comment: If any answer was helpful, indicate so.  @CodingFarmer

Comment: Also, can you tell me the reason, why just use i, rather than i, j and index ?

Comment: Just to use as less as possible variables @CodingFarmer

Answer (score 0):

in the third loop you use i and j as index for the integer1 and integer2, so you are trying to access the 11 item of these two arrays which doesn't exist. so your code i think should be like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int integer1[10], integer2[10], integertotal[10];
    int i, j, index;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        integer1[i] = 2 * (i + 4);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("    %d", integer1[i]);

    printf("\n");

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        integer2[j] = 3 * (j + 3);
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        printf("    %d", integer2[j]);

    printf("\n");

    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        integertotal[index] = integer1[index] * 12 + integer2[index] * 10;
    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        printf("   %d", integertotal[index]);

    printf("\n\n");

    for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
        printf("%d %d+%d=%d\n", index, integer1[index], integer2[index], integertotal[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to add two arrays to produce a third one?

We can write a function like this one

```
void sum_arrays(size_t n, int *src_1, int *src_2, int *dest)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // Note that 'i' is local, initialized and it is used for all the arrays
        dest[i] = src_1[i] + src_2[i];
    }
}
```

That, of course, doesn't the produce the output expected by the OP, but thanks to [Bishal Jaiswal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8010985/bishal-jaiswal), who apparently reverse engineered the "correct" formula, we can use this

```
void calc_array(size_t n, int *src_1, int *src_2, int *dest)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        dest[i] = (src_1[i] * 12 + src_2[i] * 10 + (i + 1)) * 2;
        //              ^^^             ^^^         ^^^^^
    } 
}
```

Testable [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nO29W85ljQXY8tXW).

In the code posted by the asker, besides using a wrong formula, the arrays are indexed with the wrong variables

```
int integer1[10], integer2[10], integertotal[10];
int i, j, index;  // <---

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
// ...
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
// ...
// Now both 'i' and 'j' are equal to 10
// ...
for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    integertotal[index] = integer1[i] * 12 + integer2[j] * 10;
// Those are out of bounds now    ^^^                ^^^                
// ...
// Same later
for (index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    printf("%d %d+%d=%d\n", index, integer1[i], integer2[j], integertotal[index]);
//                                         ^^^          ^^^
```